# Sql: export database using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have database connection to database DB1. The only thing I could do - execute any t-sql statements including using stored procedures. I want to export the specific table (or even the specific rows of specific table) to my local database. As you can read abve, DBs are on diffrent servers meaning no direct connection is possible. Therefore question: Is it possible to write query that returns the other query to execute on local server and get data? Also note, that table contains BLOBs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the data import function on your local database to get the data. It works as long as you have Read/Select access on the tables you are trying to copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio you can use the database tools in there to move data between two servers as long as you can connect to both from your workstation.

Needs Ultimate or Premium though:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193261.aspx

RedGate has some usefull tools too:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/features

Maybe you should ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I can't connect to server database via SSRM for example, only TSQL. And that is main problem

Comment: As far as I know the data comparer uses only plain TSQL. Just like you using Management Studio to execute TSQL. It will fetch data from both servers and compare locally. It then generates TSQL to update the destination database.

Comment: Could you provide me with simple example that exports BlobField from DB1.TBL(where only TSQL exists) to DB2.TBL(SSMS,etc)?

Comment: Sorry I've only got those things at work. I added a link to RedGate in the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login to the remote db (where you can only issue t-sql), you may create linked server on your local server to the remote and use it later directly in queries, like:

```
select * from [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

Comment: And if my local sql server is available to access via Internet, is it possible to link it from the other using tsql? if I know connection string, will it be enough?